# Having trouble installing Apache Spark on MacOS

Tags: macos, apache-spark, homebrew

I am trying to set up apache spark on my Mac, I followed this guide (https://medium.freecodecamp.org/installing-scala-and-apache-spark-on-mac-os-837ae57d283f) step by step and when I run spark-shell in terminal is get this error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.0/libexec/bin/spark-shell: line 57: /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.0.1/libexec/bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best guess is during the last step where you set SPARK_HOME - the article is a little older so the spark version from brew at the time was 2.0.1, but now it's 2.2.0. If you update the path and refresh your profile it should work.